# Problems in changing countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I want to change time to 28th May, but I am not getting how to do that.

```
! function(a) {
  "use strict";
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : a(jQuery)
}(function(a) {
  "use strict";

  function b(a) {
    if (a instanceof Date) return a;
    if (String(a).match(g)) return String(a).match(/^[0-9]*$/) && (a = Number(a)), String(a).match(/\-/) && (a = String(a).replace(/\-/g, "/")), new Date(a);
    throw new Error("Couldn't cast `" + a + "` to a date object.")
  }

  function c(a) {
    var b = a.toString().replace(/([.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    return new RegExp(b)
  }

  function d(a) {
    return function(b) {
      var d = b.match(/%(-|!)?[A-Z]{1}(:[^;]+;)?/gi);
      if (d)
        for (var f = 0, g = d.length; g > f; ++f) {
          var h = d[f].match(/%(-|!)?([a-zA-Z]{1})(:[^;]+;)?/),
            j = c(h[0]),
            k = h[1] || "",
            l = h[3] || "",
            m = null;
          h = h[2], i.hasOwnProperty(h) && (m = i[h], m = Number(a[m])), null !== m && ("!" === k && (m = e(l, m)), "" === k && 10 > m && (m = "0" + m.toString()), b = b.replace(j, m.toString()))
        }
      return b = b.replace(/%%/, "%")
    }
  }

  function e(a, b) {
    var c = "s",
      d = "";
    return a && (a = a.replace(/(:|;|\s)/gi, "").split(/\,/), 1 === a.length ? c = a[0] : (d = a[0], c = a[1])), 1 === Math.abs(b) ? d : c
  }
  var f = [],
    g = [],
    h = {
      precision: 100,
      elapse: !1
    };
  g.push(/^[0-9]*$/.source), g.push(/([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source), g.push(/[0-9]{4}([\/\-][0-9]{1,2}){2}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source), g = new RegExp(g.join("|"));
  var i = {
      Y: "years",
      m: "months",
      n: "daysToMonth",
      w: "weeks",
      d: "daysToWeek",
      D: "totalDays",
      H: "hours",
      M: "minutes",
      S: "seconds"
    },
    j = function(b, c, d) {
      this.el = b, this.$el = a(b), this.interval = null, this.offset = {}, this.options = a.extend({}, h), this.instanceNumber = f.length, f.push(this), this.$el.data("countdown-instance", this.instanceNumber), d && ("function" == typeof d ? (this.$el.on("update.countdown", d), this.$el.on("stoped.countdown", d), this.$el.on("finish.countdown", d)) : this.options = a.extend({}, h, d)), this.setFinalDate(c), this.start()
    };
  a.extend(j.prototype, {
    start: function() {
      null !== this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval);
      var a = this;
      this.update(), this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        a.update.call(a)
      }, this.options.precision)
    },
    stop: function() {
      clearInterval(this.interval), this.interval = null, this.dispatchEvent("stoped")
    },
    toggle: function() {
      this.interval ? this.stop() : this.start()
    },
    pause: function() {
      this.stop()
    },
    resume: function() {
      this.start()
    },
    remove: function() {
      this.stop.call(this), f[this.instanceNumber] = null, delete this.$el.data().countdownInstance
    },
    setFinalDate: function(a) {
      this.finalDate = b(a)
    },
    update: function() {
      if (0 === this.$el.closest("html").length) return void this.remove();
      var b, c = void 0 !== a._data(this.el, "events"),
        d = new Date;
      b = this.finalDate.getTime() - d.getTime(), b = Math.ceil(b / 1e3), b = !this.options.elapse && 0 > b ? 0 : Math.abs(b), this.totalSecsLeft !== b && c && (this.totalSecsLeft = b, this.elapsed = d >= this.finalDate, this.offset = {
        seconds: this.totalSecsLeft % 60,
        minutes: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60) % 60,
        hours: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60) % 24,
        days: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24) % 7,
        daysToWeek: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24) % 7,
        daysToMonth: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 % 30.4368),
        totalDays: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24),
        weeks: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7),
        months: Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 30.4368),
        years: Math.abs(this.finalDate.getFullYear() - d.getFullYear())
      }, this.options.elapse || 0 !== this.totalSecsLeft ? this.dispatchEvent("update") : (this.stop(), this.dispatchEvent("finish")))
    },
    dispatchEvent: function(b) {
      var c = a.Event(b + ".countdown");
      c.finalDate = this.finalDate, c.elapsed = this.elapsed, c.offset = a.extend({}, this.offset), c.strftime = d(this.offset), this.$el.trigger(c)
    }
  }), a.fn.countdown = function() {
    var b = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return this.each(function() {
      var c = a(this).data("countdown-instance");
      if (void 0 !== c) {
        var d = f[c],
          e = b[0];
        j.prototype.hasOwnProperty(e) ? d[e].apply(d, b.slice(1)) : null === String(e).match(/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i) ? (d.setFinalDate.call(d, e), d.start()) : a.error("Method %s does not exist on jQuery.countdown".replace(/\%s/gi, e))
      } else new j(this, b[0], b[1])
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this a freaking library???????

Comment: ibrahim mahrir how to change countdown ???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of posting some library's code, [**read the docs**](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown). It's all in there!

```js
$('#myCountDown').countdown('2017/05/28', function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%w weeks %d days %H:%M:%S'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

<div id="myCountDown"></div>
```

Comment: $('#myCountDown').countdown('2017/05/28', function(event) {
  $(this).html(event.strftime('%w weeks %d days %H:%M:%S'));
});

how to add this script in index.php file ??